# Is ' The Full Moon ' correct?

Tags: articles

Can ' The ' be used infront of Full moon?
Yesterday I saw.... Fullmoon.   Or Yesterday I saw the Full moon.

Comment: Well, you wouldn't normally capitalize "full".

Comment: "a" full moon is probably more common but "the" full moon is fine, "a" because it happens every month while "the" would imply a specific one

Comment: Yes and please remember, "full moon" without an article isn't acceptable. Your "full moon" *must* follow an article, whether that article is a/an/any/the… or what.

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight difference.

So "a" full moon would be any full moon, they happen every month.

While "the" full moon would imply a specific one, so I saw "the" full moon last night.

ps. you wouldn't capitalise "Full" although you could capitalise Moon as the name of Earth's moon rather than any other moon